# ERROR: mysqld: Plugin 'unix_socket' already installed

Tags: mysql, mariadb

Every time I restart mysql (mariadb) I get this error :

```
[ERROR] mysqld: Plugin 'unix_socket' already installed
[Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
```

But I don't even try to enable or setup this unix_socket

[Note] mysqld (mysqld 10.1.47-MariaDB-0+deb9u1)

Comment: Odd. What version? From MariaDB-10.4 its compiled in. It hard to guess which script is trying to install it. What distro?

Comment: @danblack 10.1.47

Answer (score 0):

Delete unix_socket record from mysql.plugin table

```
select * from mysql.plugin;
+--------------+-----------------+
| name         | dl              |
+--------------+-----------------+
| SERVER_AUDIT | server_audit.so |
| pam          | auth_pam.so     |
| unix_socket  | auth_socket.so  |
+--------------+-----------------+
delete from mysql.plugin where name='unix_socket';
```